# DateFormat from ''yyyy-MM-dd" to "dd-MM" using Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I have following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM");
LocalDate weekMon = new LocalDate().withWeekOfWeekyear(thisWeek).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
System.out.println(weekMon.toString());
LocalDate weekFin = dtf.parseLocalDate(weekMon.toString());
```

and the output prints the date correctly: 2015-02-02. I'm trying to convert it to European format and ignoring the year as "dd-MM" -> "02-02" but the line:

```
LocalDate weekFin = dtf.parseLocalDate(weekMon.toString());
```

keeps throwing following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-02-02" is malformed at "5-02-02"
```

What is wrong with the formation in this case ?.

Comment: `parseLocalDate` does not do what you think it does. read the doc again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you need is to `print`, and not to `parse`.

In other words:

```
String dateStr = dtf.print(weekMon);
```

**Notice** that with this code:

```
LocalDate weekFin = dtf.parseLocalDate(weekMon.toString());
```

you are trying to parse a string in `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format using a formatter that accepts strings in `"dd/MM"` format. Hence the exception...